# App crashes on initialization views in Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to open Dialog window while clicking on some text view in recyclerview element.

Opening a window works perfectly if I don't try to initialize the texts view.
If I do, then the app crashes.

in my guestMessage setOnClickListener i'm open a Dialog.
In onClick i'm initialize TextView that should contain the texts (name and message).

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final GuestViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Guest guest = guests.get(position);
        holder.guestName.setText(guests.get(position).getGuestName());
        //holder.guestMessage.setText(guests.get(position).getGuestMessage());
        holder.guestPhoneNumber.setText(guests.get(position).getGuestPhoneNumber());
        holder.personsCount.setText(guests.get(position).getPersonsCount());

        holder.guestMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Dialog messageDialog = new Dialog(context);
                TextView name = messageDialog.findViewById(R.id.messageTitlePopUp);
                TextView message = messageDialog.findViewById(R.id.messageInPopup);
                messageDialog.setContentView(R.layout.message_dialog_popup);

                name.setText(guests.get(position).getGuestName());
                message.setText(guests.get(position).getGuestMessage());

                messageDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: most probably context is not right one.. can you share the full adapter class

Comment: I think you need to re-arrange setContentView to the second line

Comment: @Michael Have a look on the below solution, you have not used `setContentView ` , therefore you are getting the exception

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising views before setting up content view on dialog, which cause the issue.

To solve issue, just change the initialisation order for your dialog code.

```
  final Dialog messageDialog = new Dialog(context);
  messageDialog.setContentView(R.layout.message_dialog_popup);
  TextView name = messageDialog.findViewById(R.id.messageTitlePopUp);
  TextView message = messageDialog.findViewById(R.id.messageInPopup);
```